# JSON string not running properly, debugging issues

Tags: javascript, html, json, debugging

I am building a JSON String that will load bus schedules into local storage, then based on a search term provides the stops on the bus schedule. I am running into a number of errors. The first I am receiving is ',' expected at line 40. The second is 'load is not a function' at line 50. The third is 'click is not defined' at line  53. I know there are probably other problems but I cannot find a solution to the problems listed.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * A JSON string that holds data. There is no problem with the JSON string
 * @type {String}
 */

 var busSchd = '{"Routes": [{"routeName": "Milledge","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "Orbit","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "East West","stops":[{"Stop 1":"East Campus Deck","Stop 2":"Creswell Hall","Stop 3":"Hull St Deck","Stop 4":"Main Library","Stop 5":"Joe Frank Harris"}]}]}';


const load = () => {
 let data = JSON.parse(busSchd);
 console.log("a");
for(var i=0; i<data.Routes.len;)
 {
  let route = data.Routes[i];
  let routeStr = route.routeName;
  localStorage.set(routeStr,JSON.stringify(route.stops));
 }
 
};

 const clicked = () => {
  
  var search = document.getElementById("search");
  var results = localStorage.getItem(search);

  if(results = null)
  {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>There are no results for that route name.</b>"
  }
  else
  {
   var stops = results;
   var output='';
   for(var key in stops[0])
   {
    var output = output  '<b>' + key + '</b> : ' + stops[0][key] + '<br>';
   }
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
  }
 };

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Load Route Data" id="load" onclick="load();">
<br>
<br> 
<input type="text" id="search"><input type="button" value="Find Route" id="submit" onclick="clicked();"><br>
<br><br>
<div id="result">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run that through at jshint.com. I found a number of syntax errors and missing operators. Hint: `===` not `=`, and `+` is missing too.

Answer (score 0):

Found a number of minor errors. When you clean up the syntax, it all seems to work.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * A JSON string that holds data. There is no problem with the JSON string
     * @type {String}
     */

    var busSchd = '{"Routes": [{"routeName": "Milledge","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "Orbit","stops":[{"Stop 1":"Main Library","Stop 2":"Clarke Central","Stop 3":"Five Points South","Stop 4":"Five Points North","Stop 5":"Waddell"}]},{"routeName": "East West","stops":[{"Stop 1":"East Campus Deck","Stop 2":"Creswell Hall","Stop 3":"Hull St Deck","Stop 4":"Main Library","Stop 5":"Joe Frank Harris"}]}]}';

    const load = () => {
      let data = JSON.parse(busSchd);
      console.log("a");
      for (var i = 0; i < data.Routes.len;) {
        let route = data.Routes[i];
        let routeStr = route.routeName;
        localStorage.set(routeStr, JSON.stringify(route.stops));
      }
    };

    const clicked = () => {
      var search = document.getElementById("search");
      var results = localStorage.getItem(search);

      if (results === null) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>There are no results for that route name.</b>";
      } else {
        var stops = results;
        var output = '';
        for (var key in stops[0]) {
          output = output + '<b>' + key + '</b> : ' + stops[0][key] + '<br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
      }
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Load Route Data" id="load" onclick="load();">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="search"><input type="button" value="Find Route" id="submit" onclick="clicked();"><br>
  <br><br>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

It's `.setItem('key', 'value')`, not `.set()`. See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

To address this in your code, try:

```
localStorage.setItem(routeStr, JSON.stringify(route.stops));
```

Also, the search would have to be an exact match the way you have it now. You might want to consider some autocomplete suggestions. I generally use jQuery and jQuery UI, and this type of data would lend itself to jQuery UI Autocomplete. You could DIY if you wanted.

Comment: I tried your code and when I press the load button I am still not loading the data. I feel there is an issue with with the load const or the button connecting it.

Comment: My console.log is showing the load is working. However when I search a route name its coming back empty.

Comment: When I looked into my local storage I found that the load button is not actually loading the JSON. The local storage is empty.

Comment: @itstudent101 your post said you wanted to address the errors, which I did. Fixing your code is another thing.